# Are multiple (PUTs) need for Turning on/off multiple lights using lights API?

Tags: philips-hue

I am using the following script: https://github.com/callil/SparkHue/blob/master/sparkhue.ino

This is working great besides the fact that it only lets me control that one light with id 3. What is I have multiple light ID's I want to turn on / off with the light API. Do I need to make multiple calls for each?

```
                client.println("PUT /api/deviceAddress/groups/1/action HTTP/1.1");
                client.println("Connection: keep-alive"); //
                client.println("Host: 192.168.1.11"); //same as server
                client.println("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8"); //
                client.print("Content-Length: "); //param
                client.println(11+len); //brightness string + val length
                client.println();  // blank line before body
                client.print("{\"bri\": ");
                client.print(val); //value of potentiometer
                client.println("}");
                Serial.println("sent");
```

Comment: In order to clarify your expectations for an answer, have you looked at the [Philips Hue API](http://www.developers.meethue.com/)?

Comment: Yes I have. I am thinking in order to turn off my and my wife's lamp I should add them to a group and set an action there?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of performing individual commands on each light ID, you can create a group of multiple lights.

Assuming you want to perform a command on all your lights, you can use the all-lights-group, which has ID 0. Instead of using the `/lights/3/state` path, you can use a group path similarly:

```
/groups/0/action
```

To create a group you need to perform a `POST` on `/api/<username>/groups` with the IDs of the lights the group should contain and also the name of the group, but you can read it all here: [Create Group API](http://www.developers.meethue.com/documentation/groups-api#22_create_group).

Comment: But what if you don't want to control a group, but still want to turn two of four bulbs off?  Will I need to perform a PUT for each bulb, or is there a way to send an array of changes that includes multiple bulbs?

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible to send an array of changes. However, it is possible to create a rule containing up to 8 light state changes. Then assuming you want the light state changes done 'instantly' and you do not want to reuse the rule: you would need to set a rule condition to execute it one second in the future, and delete the rule with a separate command. But then you might as well create a group.

Answer (score 0):

You could dynamically create a group, perform actions, and then remove the group again afterwards..
This might only be a smart workaround if you need to apply an action to a lot of lights.

I would probably go for just using multiple puts (one for each light if its just some few), or creating a static group.